# React-Native - call a function on swipe left/right

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, swipe

I am trying to use left/right swipe to call a function on my page - I cant see an obvious way to do this?

I assume there is built in functionality to detect these kinds of gestures and then call a predefined function?

I am trying to use this as a navigation gesture - and a left and right swipe will load a component passing in a date and loading data based on that date.

Please let know if anyone can help with this.
Thanks

Comment: [Gesture Responder System](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) or [Pan Responder](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) sound like your ticket

Comment: have you got something?

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend this library as I don't know of any inbuilt function to achieve your need so easy. [Swipe gestures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures)

```
  <GestureRecognizer
    onSwipe={(direction, state) => this.onSwipe(direction, state)}
    onSwipeUp={(state) => this.onSwipeUp(state)}
    onSwipeDown={(state) => this.onSwipeDown(state)}
    onSwipeLeft={(state) => this.onSwipeLeft(state)}
    onSwipeRight={(state) => this.onSwipeRight(state)}
    config={config}
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor
    }}
    >
    <Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>
    <Text>onSwipe callback received gesture: {this.state.gestureName}</Text>
  </GestureRecognizer>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    onLeftActionComplete={() => leftComplete()}
    onRightActionComplete={() => rightComplete()}
```

Comment: when giving a SO answer, please provide also a description and not only some code. This way people can learn from your answers and not only copy/paste your suggested snippet.

Comment: @SahanDevakaLokuge, more details here?

Comment: your solution does not answer the question